# How to include a class instance in a WCF data contract?

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to set up a WCF service to pass information about a complicated object, SimCalibrationData, to a client.  SimCalibratonData contains a list of objects of type SimCalibrationBaseData.  SimCalibrationBaseData has objects of type SimPlateData.  All classes are decorated with [DataContract], and public properties are decorated with [DataMember].  If I wrap the SimPlateData objects into a List<>, I can send them to my client and they are successfully deserialized.  If I don't wrap them, I get an error saying "The server did not provide a meaningful reply" and a suggestion that there might be a contract mismatch.

I've read that lists and other collections can always be serialized and deserialized, but I haven't found anything telling me what to do if I don't want to go to the trouble wrapping all my data in lists.

Here is my server-side code:

```
[DataContract]
public class SimCalibrationData
{
    private List<SimBaseCalibrationData> m_baseCalibrations = new List<SimBaseCalibrationData>();
    [DataMember]
    public List<SimBaseCalibrationData> BaseCalibrations
    {
        get { return m_baseCalibrations; }
    }

    public SimCalibrationData(CSimThermalCalibrationList calibrationList)
    {
        foreach (CSimThermalCalibration calibration in calibrationList.Listing)
        {
            m_baseCalibrations.Add(new SimBaseCalibrationData(calibration));
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(SimPlateData))]
public class SimBaseCalibrationData
{
    // Plate Parameters
    SimPlateData m_convectorPlate;
    [DataMember]
    public SimPlateData ConvectorPlate
    {
        get { return m_convectorPlate; }
    }
    SimPlateData m_loadPlate;
    [DataMember]
    public SimPlateData LoadPlate
    {
        get { return m_loadPlate; }
    }

    public SimBaseCalibrationData(CSimThermalCalibration calibration)
    {
        m_convectorPlate = new SimPlateData(calibration.ConvectorPlate);
        m_loadPlate = new SimPlateData(calibration.LoadPlate);
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class SimPlateData
{
    public SimPlateData(CSimPlate plate)
    {
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.  In the meantime, I'll be wrapping everything in lists.

Comment: A couple of notes on DataContracts.  First, each property you want to serialize needs to have both get and set - otherwise the serialization will fail (without a setter, there's no way for the sending side to serialize the value).  Second, unless you're sharing the assembly that has the data contracts between the client and the service, methods and constructors won't do you any good, because those items are not serializable.  Only the data comes across.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I don't understand what's going on during serialization, then.  The server side has a constructor to convert from my production data into the object that will be sent.  That will initialize my data members.  But you're saying serialization will create a copy of my object and just copy the public data members without invoking the constructor?  (Actually, that sounds familiar.  I seem to remember reading that somewhere.)

Comment: Yes, that's correct, based on my understanding and experience.  All the DataContract does is tell the system to use the DataContractSerializer, which will serialize all properties marked with `[DataMember]`.  Constructors and methods won't be serialized or sent over.  It's an SOA principle - implementation is left up to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim's first comment, pointing out that serialized properties must have setters, was the answer.